# Dynamically create elemente with data- attribute and HTML inside it and insert into existing element

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I'm get data with AJAX and need to create a list dynamically.
At the begin I have:

```
<ul id="list">
</ul>
```

In the end I want to have:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li data-city-numb="001">city-1<span>country-1</span></li>
    <li data-city-numb="002">city-2<span>country-2</span></li>
</ul>
```

Now I'm stopped on this code (I know it's wrong):

```
for (var i = 0; i < numbOfCityList; i++) {
    $('<li/>', {
        text: myCityList.list[i].city + "<span>" + myCityList.list[i].county + "</span>"
    }).appendTo("#selected-list");
    $("#list").last().data(myCityList.list[i].numbid);
};
```

Comment: you need to post your ajax return as well, so that we can consider that to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't include much information, so I included my own version of city list.

You can do it in this way (although there many other possible ways to do it):

```js
var myCityList = [{
  city: 1,
  county: 1
}, {
  city: 13,
  county: 7
}];

for (var i = 0; i < myCityList.length; i++) {
  $li = $('<li/>');
  $li.attr('data-city-numb', myCityList[i].city);
  $li.html(myCityList[i].city + ", <span>" + myCityList[i].county + "</span>");
  $('#list').append($li);

  // For one-line fans:
  // $('<li>').attr('data-city-numb', myCityList[i].city).html(myCityList[i].city + ", <span>" + myCityList[i].county + "</span>").appendTo('#list');
};

  // Or even, remove even the for(...) loop: 
  // $.map(myCityList,function(i, el) { $('<li>').attr('data-city-numb', el.city).html(el.city + ", <span>" + el.county + "</span>").appendTo('#list');});

  // I prefer the first version for readability
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id='list'></ul>
```

Comment: Good solution +1, I was thinking along the same lines. However, it's not explaning as to why the code of OP is not working presently. First of all, this is because he made a very simple mistake in the ID of the `<ul>`. See my solution above. Furthermore, I don't see the point of doing 4 jQuery actions, building the <li> bit by bit, when you can also just append the ready-to-go HTML all at once. Is there an advantage to doing it your way (first adding a `li`, then giving this `li` an attribute, then filling it with content, and then appending it)?

Comment: @LaurensSwart I wanted to show that you can create a detached jquery element and treat it as if it was a real element. I prefer readabilty to putting it all in a single line, but you can easyly change it. If you need to create a complex HTML thi way is less error-prone. My solution also shows that you can add or modify an atribute with 'attr' instead of hardcoding it in an string. Unless the only problem in a question is a typo, I usually don't take it into account. If the only problem was the typo, I'd comment it, and vote it for closing. In this case, the question's code was unsalvageable.

Comment: @LaurensSwart As you're so fan about putting all the code in one line, you can now see a compact and a super-compact version of the code.

Comment: Fair enough, yet in this case pointing out the #selected-list problem is very important, since he may already have been trying many many things, and none of them worked, not because the jquery was flawd, but he simply forgot to change his `<ul id="">` ;-) Also, your "readable" version has increased execution times since it's running 4 jQuery commands per loop (per city), which may become an issue when the list of cities gets very long.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're appending something to `#selected-list` while your `<ul>` has the `id="list"`. That's why your code isn't working in the first place, because the `<ul id="selected-list">` doesn't exist!

Assuming your data is coming through (via the AJAX return) correctly, and the array you're using is actually filled with data, you should do the following:

```
$('#list').append('<li data-city-numb="' + myCityList[i].city + '">' + myCityList[i].city + ', <span>' + myCityList[i].county + '</span></li>');
```

See working example:

```js
var myCityList = [{
  city: 'Amsterdam',
  county: 'Netherlands'
}, {
  city: 'Rotterdam',
  county: 'Netherlands'
}];

for (var i = 0; i < myCityList.length; i++) {
  $('#list').append('<li data-city-numb="' + myCityList[i].city + '">' + myCityList[i].city + ', <span>' + myCityList[i].county + '</span></li>');
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
</ul>
```

Comment: Data attribute are empty.

Comment: Sorry you're right. :| I don't know why but my browser show data value only after change page...   p.s. anyway i vote for you're solution.

Comment: Thank you! Hope it helps :)